# VBA GlowFormat breaks if Radius is zero

Tags: vba

This applies to PPT and Excel as far as I have tested (2010 and 2013)
If you set the glow radius to zero, it breaks the object: for example the Color and Transparency properties are corrupted. The glow color renders as black.

Can someone confirm thius behaviour and, somebody with influence report it?

Test code detect when the Glow.Color becomes corrupted

```
Sub testGlow()
Dim sh As ShapeRange, s As Single, origColor As Long

  Set sh = Selection.ShapeRange

  With sh.Glow
    origColor = RGB(255, 240, 0)
    .Color = origColor
    s = 1
    Do
      s = s / 2
      sh.Glow.Radius = s
      DoEvents
      Debug.Print s
    Loop While .Color = origColor
  End With
  MsgBox s

End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean breaks the object? I tested in Excel 2010 and it seems OK to me. Please clarify.

Comment: According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.core.glowformat.radius.aspx), `glowformat.radius` is of the single datatype. Using 0 should not be a problem, usually.

Comment: @MarekStejskal the glow color is rendered as black and the value corrupted.

Comment: @Jens correct, that's why its a bug... It shouldn't be a problem but it is.

Comment: @CoolBlue Aah, I see it now. Well, that's obviously a bug on Microsoft side.

Comment: Small question, does the corruption happen before the 149th computation?

Comment: Hi @Jens it happens when you set it to zero, I made the loop to try to sneak up on it but its fine until you hit zero.

Comment: @Jens the link doesn't work... where can you report a bug in the MS bug reporting site?